# Factorial function produces wrong result for 21! and above

Tags: java, long-integer, factorial, integer-overflow

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    System.out.printf("%d! = %,d\n", i, factorial(i));
```

The code above initializes the factorial method below:

```
public static long factorial(int num1)
{
    if (num1 == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return Math.abs(num1 * factorial(num1 - 1));
}
```

As so the following output is created:

```
0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5,040
8! = 40,320
9! = 362,880
10! = 3,628,800
11! = 39,916,800
12! = 479,001,600
13! = 6,227,020,800
14! = 87,178,291,200
15! = 1,307,674,368,000
16! = 20,922,789,888,000
17! = 355,687,428,096,000
18! = 6,402,373,705,728,000
19! = 121,645,100,408,832,000
20! = 2,432,902,008,176,640,000
21! = 4,249,290,049,419,214,848
22! = 1,250,660,718,674,968,576
23! = 8,128,291,617,894,825,984
24! = 7,835,185,981,329,244,160
25! = 7,034,535,277,573,963,776
```

The result for 21! is wrong (it should be 51,090,942,171,709,440,000), and the result becomes completely haywire for 22! and above. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With long you can represent between  **-9,223,372,036,854,775,808** to **+9,223,372,036,854,775,807** ([source](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/02.html))so as soon the factorial pass that range you start to get errors.

Answer (score 7):

The values become erratic for the 21st value and above, because the true value is is too big for a `long`.  If you need bigger numbers, use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Minor correction: The result for `22!` is the first one that is wrong. It shows that `22! < 21!` which is obviously not true.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value that an `long` can take in Java is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and it overflows after `20!`.

You should use BigInteger for computing factorials.

For example:

```
    BigInteger n = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
        n = n.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        System.out.println(i + "! = " + n);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It all seems ok up to the `long` capacity. And why are you using Math.abs() ?

Comment: I would guess because the OP noticed the number wrapping round to negative values at 24 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obviously erratic.  see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).  You're pretty good up to 20.  after that, I'd start looking at the max value of a long (9223372036854775807).